# Understanding the set $A(n,k)$ in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone explain the meaning of the following set to me with an example: $$A(n,k)=\left\{M \in \binom{\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}}{k}\big{|}\{x_{j-1},x_{j}\} \nsubseteq M \textrm{ for } j=2,...,n\right\},$$ where $k \leqslant n$ and $|\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}|=n$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This says that $A(n,k)$ is the collection of size-$k$ subsets $M$ of the size-$n$ set $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ such that $M$ contains no consecutive pairs, e.g, $M$ cannot contain both $x_1$ and $x_2$. For example, $A(4,2)$ contains $\{x_1, x_3\}, \{x_1, x_4\}$, and $\{x_2, x_4\}$.